# Order by not working in SQL analytical functions

Tags: sql

```
create table Employee 
(
 Ename varchar (255),
 empno  integer primary key,
 deptno integer ,
 salary integer
 );
```

`

```
insert into Employee values ('Gauhar khan',1000,10,5000);
insert into Employee values ('Gauri sharma',1001,10,6000);
insert into Employee values ('Gauresh verma',1002,10,7000);
insert into Employee values ('Raja ashokan',1003,20,8000);
insert into Employee values ('Divya Nair',1004,20,19000);
insert into Employee values ('Ashwin Thakare',1005,20,10000);
insert into Employee values ('Uttam Thapa',1006,30,7800);
insert into Employee values ('Krutagnya Thakker',1007,30,11000);
insert into Employee values ('Kritika manocha',1008,30,12000);
```

`

```
select * from Employee;
```

`

```
SELECT empno,
       deptno,
       salary,
       SUM(salary) OVER(PARTITION BY deptno ORDER BY salary) AS dept_running_total
FROM Employee;
```

It returns the error :

```
Error: near line 1: near "(": syntax error
```

I have tried using only partition by clause as well still returned the same error. Please guide me in resolving the error. I tried running this over various online sql editors.

Comment: Remove the tags for the unrelated dbms. (That query wont run on all those...)

Comment: I removed the redundant tags for the multiple databases.  Only tag with the database you are really using.  The answer to your question is that not all databases support window functions.

Comment: which Database I can try. I am using SQL lite and SQL server 2014 management studio. Can you suggest where can i try to execute and build window functions ? With Sql lite it does not allow me to use partition by clause even however, with SQL server 2014 I can use partition by clause but gives error when I include Order By clause .

Comment: Try SQL Server.

Comment: @PrateekManocha: use `SQL Server`

Comment: @jarlh Which Sql server I have 2014 and tried running over the same. but it does not allow me to use order by clause over there

Comment: I have build almost the same Employee table with same columns and values and when i tried running the following command: SELECT
 empno
,deptno
,salary, 
SUM(salary) OVER (Partition by deptno order by salary) as dept_running_total from AdventureWorks1.dbo.Employee
order by empno, deptno, salary; It gave me below mentioned error "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 35
Incorrect syntax near 'order'.
"

Comment: Your query is working fine. [**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/XGTUT25857)

Comment: @zarruq Thank alot for this help.  :) Hope I can try all sort of windowing functions on the same

Comment: tried the same query in SQL server, there was no error at all.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine in SQL Server 2014. I can only assume this is not actually the query you are running

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5bfc3/1)